# Clonezilla Grub

Tags: grub, clonezilla

I am trying to restore a disk image with clonezilla. However, after I do so, a grub menu pops up showing the 4 standard options(os, recovery, memtest...). My original image did not have this and I need to skip this so the system auto boots into the OS.

I noticed clonezilla switches to using Grub 2 during the install. Is there any way to force clonezilla to use grub 1 instead of grub 2 when restoring an image?

Comment: Why not just set the default timeout to 0?

Comment: It is in the original image. Clonezilla seems to mess something up when it runs grub2

Comment: Is it this error, [After restoring, grub2 complains "error: no argument specified". Why?](http://drbl.sourceforge.net/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/114_grub2_no_argument_specified.faq#114_grub2_no_argument_specified.faq),the suspense is killing me 8-).